# How to format the np-arrays without savetxt() method?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Input data (JSON):

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "id":"77",
         "value":"hello"
      },
      {
         "id":"5",
         "value":"HI"
      },
      {
         "id":"1",
         "value":"whats up"
      },
      {
         "id":"2",
         "value":"what"
      },
      {
         "id":"120",
         "value":"hello"
      },
      {
         "id":"170",
         "value":"hello"
      },
      {
         "id":"190",
         "value":"hello"
      }
   ]
}
```

Code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
class Decoder(json.JSONDecoder):

    def decode(self, s):
        result = super(Decoder, self).decode(s)
        return self._decode(result)

    def _decode(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, str):
            try:
                return int(o)
            except ValueError:
                try:
                    return float(o)
                except ValueError:
                    return o
        elif isinstance(o, dict):
            return {k: self._decode(v) for k, v in o.items()}
        elif isinstance(o, list):
            return [self._decode(v) for v in o]
        else:
            return o

with open('ouput_data.json') as f:
    data=json.load(f,cls=Decoder)
#print(data)
list=[]
list=(data['data'])
df = pd.DataFrame(list,columns=['id','value'])
new_df = df.set_index('id')
new_df1=new_df.reindex(np.arange(1, 14)).fillna(' ')
print(new_df1)


new_df1.shape
#print(new_df1)


# In[67]:


# Specifying a formatter to convert to fixed length output
fmt = '%2s%2s%4s%1s%10s%8s%5s%1s%3s%30s%18s%2s%30s'


# In[68]:


# Remove NaNs
#in_df.fillna(' ',inplace = True)


# In[69]:

#print(in_df)
# Writing Output
filename=((data['data'])[0]['value']+".txt")
np.savetxt(filename,new_df1.values,fmt=fmt, delimiter='')
print("Done")
```

Here everything is working correct like it will format the np-arrays in the file only.But here i need the that formatted string in the variable say (Formatted_String).But savetxt method will format and save in a file only,so is there is any methods available for format the np-arrays and store in a variable.

Note: I don't want to read the file after savetxt() method and save the contents in a string.

How can i get that formatted string in a variable. Because after formatting i need to show that formatted content to the user in a screen.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203857/discussion-on-question-by-user11646543-how-to-format-the-np-arrays-without-savet).

Answer (score 0):

```
np.savetxt(filename,new_df1.values,fmt=fmt, delimiter='')
```

A formatted string with a similar display can be generated with:

```
alist = []
for row in df1.values:
    alist.append(fmt%tuple(row))
astr = '\n'.join(alist)
```

Comment: Thank you much brother...i will give a try and let you know for the queries

Comment: Why not use `array2string` in that case? I think the `.values` might be unnecessary. I will give it a try to be sure.

Comment: What is that tuple(row) what is that row? Sorry if possible explain this part only tuple(row)

Comment: Another option is to use `savetxt` to write to `io.StringIO` object.

Comment: The `%` format requires a tuple of arguments, one per '%'.  I am using basic Python string formatting (as does `savetxt`).